# A class of subsets of the sums of $\mathbb{Z}_2$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups, infinite-groups

Consider the additive group $G=\sum_{i\in I}\mathbb{Z}_2$, and for every $A\subseteq G$  put $A-A=\{a_1-a_2: a_1,a_2\in A\}$,
$$
S_A:=\{B\subseteq G: (A-A)\cap(B-B)=\{0\} , 
(A-A)+B=G\}
$$
Now, is it true that:

**(a)** For every $A\subseteq G$ all elements of $S_A$
have the same cardinal number?

Note: It seems that answer of (a) is positive if $I$ is finite (by using the GAP)
but not sure. Now if answer of (a) is negative, for some index set $I$, then
what about the following statements?

**(b)** If $I$ is infinite then there exists a subset $A$ of $G$ such that $S_A$
contains both finite and infinite elements ;

**(c)** If $I$ is infinite then there exists a subset $A$ of $G$ such that $S_A$
contains only finite elements (i.e., $|B|$'s are finite) and $\{|B|: B\in S_A\}$ is unbounded above.

Comment: Is $\mathbb Z_2$ the $2$-adic integers or the integers modulo $2$?

Comment: Yes ( $C_2$: the cyclic group of order $2$).

Comment: Do you allow $A$ and $B$ to be arbitrary subsets of $G$, or just subgroups? Also, for infinite $I$ is $G$ a direct sum or a direct product?

Comment: Yes, subsets. First we consider the direct sum.